# OpenMp - Loop/array bounds for each thread

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Is there an ICV (internal control variable) or something similar to query the upper and lower bounds of a loop in OpenMP?

The following calculation would give me the upper and lower bounds in some cases:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ){
    int this_thread = omp_get_thread_num(), 
    num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
    int lower_bound = (this_thread * n / num_threads);
    int upper_bound = ((this_thread+1) * n / num_threads) - 1;
...
}
```

For `n=100` I would get the correct lower_bound of `0, 25, 50 and 75` and upperbound of `24, 49, 74 and 99` for the threads `0, 1, 2, 3`.

If I change `n` to `99` it will give me incorrect bounds.

Does the calculation of the upper and lower bounds differ for GCC and Intel or C/C++ compilers?

Comment: The way you asked the question somehow implies that the default scheduling of your OpenMP implementation is `static`. However, although that seems to be the case for many compilers, this isn't guarantied by the OpenMP standard. Therefore you need to clarify your assumptions or to make your scheduling explicit.

Comment: Depending on scheduling, there is something called "chunks", but this is not to be confused with lower/upper bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function from the OpenMP run-time library that will give you this information. Furthermore, it will highly depend on the scheduling applied on the loop.

By default, in absence of an explicit `schedule` directive, the one that will be applied is compiler-dependent and unspecified by the OpenMP standard. Many compilers will use a `static` scheduling, but that isn't always the case, and definitely not guaranteed.

Now, just to quote the OpenMP standard about static scheduling:

> When `schedule(static, chunk_size)` is specified, iterations are divided
>   into chunks of size `chunk_size`, and the chunks are assigned to the
>   threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the
>   thread number.
>
> When no `chunk_size` is specified, the iteration space is
>   divided into chunks that are approximately equal in size, and at most
>   one chunk is distributed to each thread. The size of the chunks is
>   unspecified in this case.

As you can see, even in this simple case, if no chunk size is given and the number of threads doesn't evenly divide the number of iterations, you cannot determine reliably the lower and upper bounds of each threads' iterations.

If you define properly the size of chunks however, you should be able to compute reliably the bounds of iterations for each threads.

Now if your scheduling isn't static, then there's absolutely no way of inferring which thread will get what iteration, since this will be only defined at run-time.

Answer (score -1):

There **are no** upper/lower bounds per thread. Each thread will pick the next available element, or next available chunk of elements, in the sequence. The chunk size is configurable.

Typically, an atomic increment will used internally, i.e. InterlockedIncrement().

Having lower/upper bounds per thread would be a really bad idea by the way. Suppose that element 27 takes 10 times longer to execute compared to the rest. Then the unlucky thread that would have to process this element would finish much later than the other threads. Specific thread can also be stalled by other CPU activity, having a fixed number of elements per thread will be very inefficient.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Let me add that I never use OpenMP because it is hard to know what actually happens in the background. OpenMP, as I see it, is "threading for noobs", which inevitably leads to disaster because threading is an expert topic :)

Comment: You are absolutely right, but if my answer is wrong and there are bounds per thread, it is easy for you to simply provide a better answer.